# Show that $\langle Tx,Ty\rangle_1=\langle y, x\rangle$ defines an inner product on $H\mbox{*}$ that induces a norm on $H\mbox{*}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products, dual-spaces, isometry

The correspondence $T:H\rightarrow H\mbox{*}$ by $y\mapsto f_y$, and $y\in H$ and $T$ is a conjugate-linear isometry. We call $H\mbox{*}$ the dual space. We know that something is conjugate-linear if $$T(\lambda u+\mu v)=\bar{\lambda} Tu+\bar{\mu} Tv$$ for all $u\in X,v\in Y$ and $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{F}$. And isometry being $||Tx||=||x||$

We want to show that $$\langle Tx,Ty\rangle_1=\langle y,x\rangle$$ defines an inner product on $H\mbox{*}$ that induces a norm on $H\mbox{*}$.

I know that I am supposed to show that $$||x||=0\iff x=0$$
$$\text{Triangle Inequality}$$
$$||\alpha x||=|\alpha|||x||$$
But I am struggling with the exact steps to do this.

I will post what I have in a little if you would be more open to checking what I have.

This is what I was thinking but for some reason I just felt like it wasn't quite right.

[(a)][$||x||=0 \iff x=0$]:
\begin{align*}
    ||Tx||&=0\\
    ||Tx||^2&=\\
    \langle Tx,Tx\rangle_1&=\\
    \langle x,x\rangle&=0\iff x=0\\
\end{align*}
[(b)][$||\alpha x||=|\alpha|||x||$]:
\begin{align*}
    ||T\alpha x||&=||\bar{\alpha}Tx||\\
    &=||\bar{\alpha} x||\\
    &=|\alpha|||x||\\
    &=|\alpha|||Tx||
\end{align*}
[(c)][Triangle inequality]:
\begin{align*}
    ||Tx+Ty||&=||x+y||\\
    &\leq||x||+||y||\\
    &=||Tx||+||Ty||
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said you haven't proved that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1$ defines an inner product. I will give you some hints:
$$\langle f,g\rangle_1 := \langle T^{-1}g,T^{-1}f\rangle$$
for every $f,g \in H^*$. Prove that:
$$\langle f,g\rangle_1 = \overline{\langle g,f\rangle}_1$$
$$\langle \mu f + \lambda h,g\rangle_1 = \mu \langle f,g\rangle_1 + \lambda \langle h,g\rangle_1$$
$$\langle f,f\rangle_1 \geq 0$$
$$\langle f,f\rangle_1 = 0 \; \text{iff} \; f=0$$
all follows from the properties of $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt does not show what it should.

You are supposed to show that $\langle Tx,T_y\rangle_1:= \langle y,x\rangle$ defines an inner product. Nowhere in your attempt you even speak about an inner product.